# Intel Compute Sticks running Ubuntu shut down/crash while running digital signage

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

So i'm trying to run a handful of Intel Compute Sticks to display signage for my dad. I set them up to never go to sleep or shut off the display in Ubuntu's GUI, plugged them in and left.

But now, a couple months later, I return to find all of the sticks off. The little blue power light is on but plugging in a keyboard and mashing keys did nothing, so it didn't go to sleep. The sticks also didn't respond ssh requests or pings. They must have "shut off" somehow even with the power light on. However, they do come back on if I hold down the power button

I'm trying to figure out what happened. Is there a log somewhere that might tell me if they crashed? Or is there some hidden setting that might cause it to shut down after a few weeks?

They're all in hard to reach places, so pressing the power button every once in a while is not a viable option. I'd like these to be able to run for a long time without any human interference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out. After power loss or crash the grub menu had no default time out. I set that to 10 seconds and that appears to have fixed it.